# Displaying multiple images onload from servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets

I need to display the multiple images onload which are stored in the server , the database contains the filepath and filename .the servlet would query the sql server to get the filenames.

i need to do that on home.jsp .

when i use the below code browser shows onLoadDisplayImages as url  , i want to use it using ajax  and should stay in home.jsp . please help.

```
<script language="javascript">
function OnStartup(){
    var url = "onLoadDisplayImages";
    document.location.href='onLoadDisplayImages';
}
window.onload = OnStartup;
</script>
```

onLoadDisplayImages is servlet which just returns the filename .

below is the code

```
String imageUrl = "images/siguptop.JPG";
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write(imageUrl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax to load your images. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: calling the function onLoadDisplayImages in the ajax worked instead of OnStartup .. thanks